# Hourly and daily crons are not running

Tags: bash, cron

I've noticed that hourly and daily crons are not running, I moved them to crontab, and everything is fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date)
echo 'It is '$now
```

The command line:

```
# run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

returned blank

EDIT:

```
# ls -lsAF
total 8
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Apr  2  2012 .placeholder
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 254 Mar 18 06:52 testEcho*
```

Before the name was "testEcho**.sh**", I renamed it to "testEcho"

```
# run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.hourly/testEcho
```

Now the value was returned, I will test it and get back to you

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to AU !  Please list the full content  of yr `/etc/cron.hourly` using the `ls -lsAF /etc/cron.hourly` cmd and add it to yr post by editing it. Notify me of yr edit using @Cbhihe in a subsequent comment below.

Comment: @Cbhihe : code edited above

Comment: @heemayl beat me to the answer. I was precisely thinking about non standard spelling of file names in relation to the `--lsbsysinit` and `--regex` options.  You will find looking at  `man run-parts` very useful in that context. Heemayl nailed it while I was asleep !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hourly and daily (and also weekly, monthly)`cron` jobs are run by `run-parts` command. My `/etc/crontab` has:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

The thing to note is that `run-parts` is very sensitive to file names. From `man run-parts`:

> If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given
>   then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case
>   letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

So as the file is named `testEcho**.sh**`, it fails the name checking of `run-parts` and hence `run-parts` ignores it.

You need to rename the file(s) to conform to the `run-parts` naming policy or you can execute the files directly by adding relevant entry in `crontab`.

Comment: This is exactly it ! Kudos +1 ;-)

Comment: @Cbhihe  stolen your answer ;)

Comment: No, I wouldn't say stolen. You were faster and your time zone was more favorable. I guess I'll have to quit sleeping from now on. Congrats ;-P